# How to add section header/footer view when using AsyncDisplayKit?

Tags: ios, uitableview, sectionheader, asyncdisplaykit

It seems that currently `ASTableNode` and `ASTableView` both lack the support of section header/footer view.

I cannot only find a protocol method:

```
- (nullable NSString *)tableNode:(ASTableNode *)tableNode titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

which shows nothing.

And the delegate/dataSource setter methods have been intercepted by AsyncDisplayKit, so that I cannot use the UIKit's way to do it.

So can I add section header/footer view when I'm using AsyncDisplayKit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just find out that `ASTableNode` will call the `UITableViewDelegate` methods.

So just implement the methods

```
- (nullable UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

And it will work just like before.

Comment: Except this requires you to use UIKit (UIView) and not AsyncDisplayKit 